# Comment on JavaScript may cause "Uncaught ReferenceError :XXX is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, vue.js

I use visual studio to edit JavaScript and Nodejs. Here I encounter a weird problem:
(I include socket.io, vue, on the page )

When I add comment on `<script></script>` in `index.html` and run on localhost, Chrome console shows:  `Uncaught ReferenceError :XXX is not defined` as below:

[image]

Then removing the comment(I didn't do anything else!) as below:
run again , no error is found.

[image]

I also tried `window.onload` but didn't help.

I did spend a whole night try to figure out what may cause this problem, but no idea come out, someone could offer me some suggestion about why it happens? thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you comment. show us some code pls-

Comment: /*var onlineNum={ number:'Hello World!'};
  
  var vmOnLineNum=new Vue({ 
     el:'#aa', //binding  the onlineCount view
   data:onlineNum 
       
  });*/

Comment: could be that /* */ + // breaks the comment somehow when compiled in node.js. did you try to comment everything (every line) just with //?

Comment: yes. I try to use /* */ comment the whole block , however //  is inside in the block.

Comment: it looks like a bug of nodejs  compiler .When I remove the comment one by one , only   /*   });   */    left ,  no error occur , but there is a extra <   sign appear on the   page shows , however I guess it  relates with the comment.